# How to display a Admob Test add on external S3 Mini?

Tags: java, android

I have done the following:
1. Added dependencies in app build.gradle as well as a string with the 'dummy ad id from google' - from google's help docs
[image]

2. I have added the following xml and java code, my device ID I obtained for th LOGCAT after having filtered with the tag: 'Ad'

[image]
[image]

If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Admob banner in you have to show testing admob and display that can be you can add to test device and divice address, but i give you simple code that can be you can test your banner and put admob banner id, See below code may help you.

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```